# Angular/MVC: Sending data to controller in backend

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I would like to send the array **customparameters** from my *Angular 4* frontend to my *ASP.NET MVC* controller in the backend.

I receive the array in my ng-service.ts and would like to send it to the backend like this:

```
setCustomParameters(customparameters) {
    console.log(customparameters); //it's working

    this.http.post('/api/customparameter', customparameters). //is that right?
      subscribe();
  }
```

But I am not sure, if this is all I have to do. On the other hand I can't find via google how I have to write my controller method in the backend:

```
// POST: api/customparameter
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value) //how to change?
    {
     //doing something
    }
```

Hopefully someone has time and pleasure to help me. Thanks in forward!

Comment: You will need to create a view model based on the customparameters. Could you show the output of `console.log(customparameters);`?

Comment: have you tried all the `[Form...]` attributes? or you can manually set the request type to json

Comment: In `public void Post([FromBody]string value)` the string is not right. not matter that you get your result with `[FromBody] ` or `[FromForm]` because it just change the **javascript** side code. If the `customparameter` have a _specification_ _model_ you can create a class model in **backend** and replace **string** with it. I suggest to pass **Json** instead of  **Array** to your **Controller** because it was easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
    setCustomParameters(customparameters) {
    console.log(customparameters); //it's working

    // Converting to json
    var json = JSON.parse(customparameters);
    this.http.post('/api/customparameter', json). //is that right?
      subscribe();
  }
```

At this point JSON will be converted to the object. So properties has to match.

```
// POST: api/customparameter
   // Here we are changing type.
    [HttpPost("customparameter")]
    public void Post([FromBody]List<CustomModel> value) //how to change?
    {
     //doing something
    }
```

If on client side you passing an array of objects with lets say Id and Name you will have to create same model on backend.

```
public class CustomModel {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and example of the json will be :

```
[
  {"id" : 1, "name": "foo"},
  {"id" : 2, "name" : "bar"}
]
```

Hope that will help.